# Disable symfony 2 csrf token protection on ajax submit

Tags: ajax, symfony, csrf

i'm building a mobile app talking to my symfony2 app via webservices
I can't find a way to disable csrf protection on a specific controller/action

i want to post registration data to this action and use sf2 form validation. I do not call the form in my mobile app

Can't change container parameters in action, throw an exception because it is a frozen parameter...

I do not want to disable form protection for whole my application

any clue ?

thanks !

**update: with symfony 2.1.x**

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'csrf_protection'   => false,
    ));
}
```

Comment: `$form = $this->createForm($formType, $entity, array('csrf_protection' => false));`

Comment: Didn't investigate more but using a form type as a service i had to use SalmanPK's solutions since default csrf_protection option was not recognised.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

If you're looking for a bit easier and faster solution than suggested in answer above, here's how:

```
<?php

// ...

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class MyType extends AbstractType
{
    // ...

   public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ));
    }
}
```

.. or if you're using older versions (Symfony 2.0.*):

```
<?php

// ...

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class MyType extends AbstractType
{
    // ....

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        $options = parent::getDefaultOptions($options);
        $options['csrf_protection'] = false;

        return $options;
    }
}
```

Consult the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#csrf-protection) for additional information.

---

**Edit:** updated answer to latest Symfony version, thanks 
[naitsirch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1119601/naitsirch)

Comment: Thanks !
i was looking for implementing a custom csrf provider like @jperovic, but your solution works and is clean :)

Comment: Definitely simpler solution! :)

Comment: missing a disableCSRFProtection() method like a symfony 1.
Really convenient in ajax context

Comment: It's time to add the new >=2.7 method replacing getDefaultOptions

Comment: [>=2.7: `configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)`](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-form-and-validator-updates#deprecated-setdefaultoptions-in-favor-of-configureoptions)

Comment: The first snippet (configureOptions) works in Symfony 4.

Comment: I allowed myself to rewrite "or if you're using Symfony 2.0" in something more explicit today (No doubt at the time of writting this was clear, but today I didn't knew in reading whereas it was meaning "older versions" or "newer versions"). Feel free to accept / modify / revert my edit.

Answer (score 20):

## Using the form factory

For those who want to create a simple form in a controller:

```
$form = $this->container->get('form.factory')
    ->createNamedBuilder(null, 'form', null, array('csrf_protection' => false))
    ->add('yourField','text', array(
        'label' => false,
        'mapped' => false
    ))
    ->getForm();
```

Answer (score 8):

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'csrf_protection' => false,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked for Symfony 4 app. In my case I put this code in the file `src/Form/MovieType.php`

Answer (score 2):

## Using the form factory in Symfony 3

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;

$form = $this->container->get('form.factory')
    ->createNamedBuilder(null, FormType::class, null, array('csrf_protection' => false))
    ->add('yourField','text', array(
        'label' => false,
        'mapped' => false
    ))
    ->getForm();
```

Adapted from Mick's answer

Answer (score 1):

I can't be 100% sure but I think I read somewhere that you can pass `csrf_provider` option while creating form.

All providers are subtypes of interface `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Csrf\CsrfProvider` and you should be able to create your own:

```
class MyNonCsrfProvider extends DefaultCsrfProvider{
    public function isCsrfTokenValid($intention, $token)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and in controller:

```
$this->createForm(new CustomFormType(), array(
    'csrf_provider' => new MyNonCsrfProvider()
));
```

I haven't tried this myself but this sounds like a possible solution...