# Symfony Form, CSRF token missing

Tags: symfony, field, token, csrf

Like in the topic, i have problem with CSRF token missing. This is my form:

```
$builder
            ->add('email', 'email', array(
                'label' => 'Adres e-mail'
            ))
            ->add('userFirstname', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Imię',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('userLastname', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Nazwisko',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('userBusiness', 'entity', array(
                'label' => 'Firma',
                'required' => false,
                'class' => 'Cloud\CrmBundle\Entity\RelationContact',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->where("u.type = 'b'");
                },
                'empty_value' => true
            ))
            ->add('old_password', 'password', array(
                'label' => 'Stare hasło',
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('new_password', 'repeated', array(                
                'first_options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Nowe hasło'),
                'second_options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Powtórz nowe hasło'),
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'type' => 'password'
            ));
```

My view:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
            {{ form_row(form.email) }}
            {{ form_row(form.userFirstname) }}
            {{ form_row(form.userLastname) }}
            {{ form_row(form.userBusiness) }}
        {{ form_row(form.old_password) }}
        {{ form_row(form.new_password) }}
        </div>
</div>
```

What's wrong guys? Any ideas? :( I just don't understand this strange error... What could cause that ?

Comment: Quite simple, you need to call `{{ form_rest(form)` OR `{{ form_widget(form._token) }}`

Comment: ... or set form parameter `csrf_protection` to `FALSE` in order to disable CSRF check altogether....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you've to add this _token by hand because you're trying to display form manually:

```
{{ form_widget(form._token) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Symfony2 set a hidden field with the required informations. For this you have to include the hidden fields with:

```
{{ form_widget(form._token) }}
```

if you don't want the CSRF-Protection then you can disable the dunction in your parameters file.

[Disable symfony 2 csrf token protection on ajax submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887451/disable-symfony-2-csrf-token-protection-on-ajax-submit)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `form_start` and `form_end` symfony will add the token field to the form automatically

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_row(form.email) }}
        {{ form_row(form.userFirstname) }}
        {{ form_row(form.userLastname) }}
        {{ form_row(form.userBusiness) }}
        {{ form_row(form.old_password) }}
        {{ form_row(form.new_password) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
```