# Why doesn't Symfony 2.7 add the CSRF-token automatically to my form?

Tags: symfony

Here is the situation, I have a form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    foreach ($this->attributeGroupAttributes as $attribute) {
        $builder->add('attribute-' . $attribute->getId(), $attribute->getType(), array(
            'label' => $attribute->getName(),
        ));
    }
}.
```

This form I'm using to validate data added dynamically to another form which was submitted.

This is the process how I do it:

1. I extract the data from the previous form.
2. I pass this data to another Action.
3. Here I get the attributeGroup.
4. I pass the Attributes in that group into the FormType and create a new form.
5. After which I put the data into the form via:

   ```
   $form_validate->submit($normalizedData);
   ```

This is the controller:

```
    public function createAction($formData) {

    $itemService = $this->get('app.item');
    $attributeGroupService = $this->get('app.attribute_group');
    $attributeService = $this->get('app.attribute');

    $attributeGroup = $attributeGroupService->getById($formData['attributeGroup']);
    $attributeGroupAttributes = $attributeGroup->getAttributes();
    $form_validate = $this->createForm(new \AppBundle\Form\ItemValidationType($attributeGroupAttributes));

    $normalizedData = $itemService->normalizeDataForForm($formData);

    $form_validate->submit($normalizedData);

    if($form_validate->isValid()){
        dump($form_validate->getData());
        die();
    }
    die();
}
```

The error I get is:

```
-errors: array:1 [▼
0 => FormError {#855 ▼
  -message: "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form."
  #messageTemplate: "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form."
  #messageParameters: []
  #messagePluralization: null
  -cause: null
  -origin: Form {#836}
}
```

And that way ofcourse $form_validate->isValid() is false.

Comment: How do you render your form?

Comment: This form isn't rendered. Its existence is limited to the controller.

Comment: So where the token should come from in your opinion?

Comment: I thought it was automatically included once the form is created. Although I was slowly starting to have the suspicion that it is added once it is rendered.

Comment: It's not about creation of the token, but about providing it to pass validation.

Comment: Could you please explain how to do that? I'm currently trying with finishView

Comment: Why not just disable csrf checking with 'csrf_protection' => false, in your form options?  It also seems a bit convoluted to use a from just for validation.  Maybe it makes sense but maybe you could just use the validator directly.

Comment: I tried that, but it somehow ignores it. I have no idea why...

Comment: Try harder?  Maybe update your question with how you tried to disable it.  I would expect the accepted answer to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887451/disable-symfony-2-csrf-token-protection-on-ajax-submit

Comment: 'csrf_protection'=>false suddenly started working...(?) I have no idea why. Sorry for wasting your time.